# Помогите новичку плз

Tags: python

Как из результатов цикла сделать список?
А потом посчитать их суму.

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста пример того , что вы делаете и объясните лучше, что у вас не получается.

Comment: У вас есть 64 коробки, в первей коробке лежит 1 шар, в каждой следующей лежит в 2 раза больше чем в предыдущей. Посчитать количество всех шаров

Comment: ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Можно посчитать и без цикла:

```
print(2 ** 64 - 1)
```

Comment: Это для тех кто учил математику)

Answer (score 1):

Я удивлен, что вы знаете сколько коробок у меня есть. Я посчитал сколько шаров в моих коробках так:

```
print(sum([ 2**i for i in range(64) ]))
```